# Docker push to Artifactory fails - unable to ping resgistry endpoint

Tags: ssl, nginx, docker, artifactory

I am using Artifactory backed up by nginx as the proxy server. The nginx load balancer is configured with SSL certs from a trusted authority. I created a local docker repo and need to push images but get the following error:

```
unable to ping registry endpoint https://myArtifactory.com/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://myArtifactory.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://myArtifactory.com/v1/_ping: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I am using the following command to push images

```
docker push myArtifactory.com/ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this bya dding the certificate to the docker client under /etc/docker/certs.d